# unix - head AND tail of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Say you have a txt file, what is the command to view the top 10 lines and bottom 10 lines of file simultaneously?

i.e. if the file is 200 lines long, then view lines 1-10 and 190-200 in one go.

Comment: What do you mean "in one go" ?

Comment: @cnicutar ie. not going head -10 file *looking at the data* and then separately going tail -10 file and *looking at the data*

Comment: @toop If you want a real working example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849814/99834

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You can simply:

```
(head; tail) < file.txt
```

And if you need to uses pipes for some reason then like this:

```
cat file.txt | (head; tail)
```

Note: will print duplicated lines if number of lines in file.txt is smaller than default lines of head + default lines of tail.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't give you the tail of the original file, but the tail of the stream after `head` has consumed the first 10 lines of the file. (Compare this with `head < file.txt; tail < file.txt` on a file with fewer than 20 lines). Just a very minor point to keep in mind. (But still +1.)

Comment: Nice. If you want a gap between the head and tail parts:  (head;echo;tail) < file.txt

Comment: Curious about why/how this works. Asked it as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718242/

Comment: @chepner: [`{ tee >(head >&2) | tail; } 2>&1 < file.txt` instead of `{ head; tail; } < file.txt` supports overlapping lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20388399/4279) if you need it. `{}` instead of `()` are to avoid creating a subshell.

Comment: addition to @chepner 's comment: `(head;less) < file.txt` will show the remaining lines (line 11+) after `head`

Comment: @nametal Actually, you might not even get that much. While `head` only *displays* the first 10 lines of its input, there is no guaranteed that it didn't *consume* more of it in order to find the 10th line ending, leaving less of the input for `less` to display.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the answer only works in some cases. `seq 100 | (head; tail)` gives me only first 10 numbers. Only on much larger input size (like `seq 2000`) the tail gets some input.

Comment: I use it to check time from log file. `(head -n1; tail -n1) < file.txt`

Comment: Maybe this is possible : `cat file.txt | (head; tail)`

Comment: @alkar @J.F.Sebastian `seq 100 | { tee >(head >&2) | tail; } 2>&1;` also works to avoid the problem that we don't know how much head consumes from the stream

Comment: If you want to avoid duplication of lines see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849814/99834

Comment: @chepner I get the first and last line with `(head -n1; tail -1)`: `cat FILE | (head -n1; tail -1)`.  What system are you running these on/are these the GNU versions of the above commands?

Comment: @chepner Note: I still get the actual first and last line even with `(head; tail) < FILE`.  I'm using GNU coreutils version 8.4

Comment: this is not working for me on a 89 lines text file on macos and I have tried both the native `head`/`tail` and also `ghead` and `gtail`. Only `head` is printing some text.

Comment: Note: The buffering issue (head swallows to much from the input stream on small files so that no tail is printed) is fixed by an answer below: `cat file.txt | (sed -u 10q ; echo ; tail)`

Comment: This solution seems to sometimes work and sometimes not. So far the `sed -u` solution mentioned in the comments here and in one of the answers, appears to work for me.

Comment: Hi @modular, this is a buffering issue and can be avoided with `stdbuf -oL -eL seq 100 | (head; tail)` which enables line buffering for STDOUT and STDERR. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Answer (score 25):

`ed` is the `standard text editor`

```
$ echo -e '1+10,$-10d\n%p' | ed -s file.txt
```

Comment: What if the file has more or less than 200 lines? And you don't know the number of lines ab initio?

Comment: @Paul I've changed `sed` to `ed`

Answer (score 24):

```
(sed -u 10q; echo ...; tail) < file.txt
```

Just another variation on the `(head;tail)` theme, but avoiding the initial buffer fill issue for small files.

Comment: This worked best for me, but for the Mac, I had to `brew install gnu-sed` to get this to work.

Answer (score 22):

For a pure stream (e.g. output from a command), you can use 'tee' to fork the stream and send one stream to head and one to tail.  This requires using either the '>( list )' feature of bash (+ /dev/fd/N):

```
( COMMAND | tee /dev/fd/3 | head ) 3> >( tail )
```

or using /dev/fd/N (or /dev/stderr) plus subshells with complicated redirection:

```
( ( seq 1 100 | tee /dev/fd/2 | head 1>&3 ) 2>&1 | tail ) 3>&1
( ( seq 1 100 | tee /dev/stderr | head 1>&3 ) 2>&1 | tail ) 3>&1
```

(Neither of these will work in csh or tcsh.)

For something with a little better control, you can use this perl command:

```
COMMAND | perl -e 'my $size = 10; my @buf = (); while (<>) { print if $. <= $size; push(@buf, $_); if ( @buf > $size ) { shift(@buf); } } print "------\n"; print @buf;'
```

Comment: +1 for stream support. You could reuse stderr: `COMMAND | { tee >(head  >&2) | tail; } |& other_commands`

Comment: btw, it breaks for files larger than the buffer size (8K on my system). `cat >/dev/null` fixes it: `COMMAND | { tee >(head >&2; cat >/dev/null) | tail; } |& other_commands`

Comment: I loved the solution, but after playing for a a while I noticed that in some cases the tail was running before the head ... there are no guaranteed ordering between `head` and `tail` commands :\ ...

Answer (score 7):

Based on [J.F. Sebastian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624669/unix-head-and-tail-of-file?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment30444814_20388399):

```
cat file | { tee >(head >&3; cat >/dev/null) | tail; } 3>&1
```

This way you can process first line and the rest differently in one pipe, which is useful for working with CSV data:

```
{ echo N; seq 3;} | { tee >(head -n1 | sed 's/$/*2/' >&3; cat >/dev/null) | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1*2}'; } 3>&1
```

```
N*2
2
4
6
```

Answer (score 6):

It took make a lot of time to end-up with this solution which, seems to be the only one that covered all use cases (so far):

```
command | tee full.log | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 awk -v offset=${MAX_LINES:-200} \
          '{
               if (NR <= offset) print;
               else {
                   a[NR] = $0;
                   delete a[NR-offset];
                   printf "." > "/dev/stderr"
                   }
           }
           END {
             print "" > "/dev/stderr";
             for(i=NR-offset+1 > offset ? NR-offset+1: offset+1 ;i<=NR;i++)
             { print a[i]}
           }'
```

Feature list:

- live output for head (obviously that for tail is not possible)
- no use of external files
- progressbar one dot for each line after the MAX_LINES, very useful for long running tasks.
- progressbar on stderr, assuring that the progress dots are separated from the head+tail (very handy if you want to pipe stdout)
- avoids possible incorrect logging order due to buffering (stdbuf)
- avoid duplicating output when total number of lines is smaller than head + tail.

Comment: This is the best answer here. I added it to my `.bashrc` in a function so I can just pipe to `headtail`.

Answer (score 5):

`head -10 file.txt; tail -10 file.txt`

Other than that, you'll need to write your own program / script.

Comment: Nice, I have always used `cat` and `head` or `tail` piped, good to know that I can use them individually!

Comment: How can I then pipe these first 10+last 10 into another command?

Comment: `head file.txt; tail file.txt | your_program`

Comment: @Paul - with 'your_program' as wc -l it returns 10 instead of 20

Comment: `(head .vimrc ; tail .vimrc) | wc -l`

Comment: or, without having to spawn a subshell: `{ head file; tail file; } | prog` (spacing inside the braces, and the trailing semicolon are required)

Comment: Wow... a down-vote for having an answer quite similar to others (yet timestamped before them) after almost two years, from someone who chose not to post why they down-voted. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

the problem here is that stream-oriented programs don't know the length of the file in advance (because there might not be one, if it's a real stream).

tools like `tail` buffer the last n lines seen and wait for the end of the stream, then print.

if you want to do this in a single command (and have it work with any offset, and do not repeat lines if they overlap) you'll have to emulate this behaviour I mentioned.

try this awk:

```
awk -v offset=10 '{ if (NR <= offset) print; else { a[NR] = $0; delete a[NR-offset] } } END { for (i=NR-offset+1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i] }' yourfile
```

Comment: it needs more work in order to avoid issues when offset is larger than the file

Comment: Yay, this works with piped output, not just files:  `a.out | awk -v ...`

Comment: indeed :) but that's awk's normal behavior, most commandline programs work on stdin when invoked without arguments.

Comment: Very close to the desired behaviour but it seems that for <10 lines it does add extra new lines.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always chain them together. Like so,
`head fiename_foo && tail filename_foo`. If that is not sufficient, you could write yourself a bash function in your .profile file or any login file that you use:

```
head_and_tail() {
    head $1 && tail $1
}
```

And, later invoke it from your shell prompt: `head_and_tail filename_foo`.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for this solution for a while. Tried it myself with sed, but the problem with not knowing the length of file/stream beforehand was insurmountable. Of all the options available above, I like Camille Goudeseune's awk solution. He did make a note that his solution left extra blank lines in the output with a sufficiently small data set. Here I provide a modification of his solution that removes the extra lines.

```
headtail() { awk -v offset="$1" '{ if (NR <= offset) print; else { a[NR] = $0; delete a[NR-offset] } } END { a_count=0; for (i in a) {a_count++}; for (i=NR-a_count+1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i] }' ; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First 10 lines of file.ext, then its last 10 lines:

`cat file.ext | head -10 && cat file.ext | tail -10`

Last 10 lines of the file, then the first 10:

`cat file.ext | tail -10 && cat file.ext | head -10`

You can then pipe the output elsewhere too:

`(cat file.ext | head -10 && cat file.ext | tail -10 ) | your_program`

Comment: Why use cat when you can just call head -10 file.txt?

Comment: Can you make the number of lines variable, so the call is something like: head_ tail(foo, m,n) - returning the first m snd last n lines of text?

Comment: @ricardo that would involve writing a bash script that takes 3 args and passes them to `tail` and `head` or a function by alias-ing it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple python app to do this: https://gist.github.com/garyvdm/9970522

It handles pipes (streams) as well as files.

Comment: Would be best to post the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Basically, it uses  [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to simulate tail

Answer (score 1):

drawing on ideas above  (tested bash & zsh)

but using an alias 'hat' Head and Tails

```
alias hat='(head -5 && echo "^^^------vvv" && tail -5) < '


hat large.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Consumes stdin, but simple and works for 99% of use cases

#### head_and_tail

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
COUNT=${1:-10}
IT=$(cat /dev/stdin)
echo "$IT" | head -n$COUNT
echo "..."
echo "$IT" | tail -n$COUNT
```

#### example

```
$ seq 100 | head_and_tail 4
1
2
3
4
...
97
98
99
100
```

Comment: I was searching for a head and tail solution, after created an one-liner.
I enhanced this solution to set -n
see: https://github.com/rundekugel/myScripts/blob/master/hat.sh

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `sed` for this task?

`sed -n -e 1,+9p -e 190,+9p  textfile.txt`

Comment: This works for files of known length, but not files whose length is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

To handle pipes (streams) as well as files, add this to your .bashrc or .profile file:

```
headtail() { awk -v offset="$1" '{ if (NR <= offset) print; else { a[NR] = $0; delete a[NR-offset] } } END { for (i=NR-offset+1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i] }' ; }
```

Then you can not only

```
headtail 10 < file.txt
```

but also

```
a.out | headtail 10
```

(This still appends spurious blank lines when 10 exceeds the input's length, unlike plain old `a.out | (head; tail)`.  Thank you, previous answerers.)

Note: `headtail 10`, not `headtail -10`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @Samus_ explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16205126/3297903) about how @Aleksandra Zalcman's command works, this variation is handy when you can't quickly spot where the tail begins without counting lines.

```
{ head; echo "####################\n...\n####################"; tail; } < file.txt
```

Or if you start working with something other than 20 lines, a line count might even help.

```
{ head -n 18; tail -n 14; } < file.txt | cat -n
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the first 10 and last 10 lines of a file, you could try this:

`cat <(head -n10 file.txt) <(tail -n10 file.txt) | less`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "1,10p; $(( $(wc -l ${aFile} | grep -oE "^[[:digit:]]+")-9 )),\$p" "${aFile}"
```

**NOTE**: The **aFile** variable contains the file's **full path**.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that depending upon the size of the file, actively reading in its contents may not be desirable. In that circumstance, I think some simple shell scripting should suffice.

Here's how I recently handled this for a number of very large CSV files that I was analyzing:

```
$ for file in *.csv; do echo "### ${file}" && head ${file} && echo ... && tail ${file} && echo; done
```

This prints out the first 10 lines and the last 10 lines of each file, while also printing out the filename and some ellipsis before and after.

For a single large file, you could simply run the following for the same effect:

```
$ head somefile.csv && echo ... && tail somefile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more experimenting based mostly on suggestions here. After working a bit, I up with something very similar to another version in another comment, but with a focus more on formatting with multiple file args in addition to stdin.

This wraps nicely into a script (tentatively `headtail`) and uses the gnu awk. On macOs this can be installed via `brew install gawk`.

It can work on piped content OR a list of files as arguments.
Given files, it prints a header of the file name, the head N lines, a skipped lines maker, then the tail N lines. If the head and tail overlap or would line up, it neither includes a skip marker nor does it display any duplicate lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
headtail_awk() {
  N=10
  gawk -v "n=${N}" -- '\
  FNR == 1 && FILENAME != "-" {
    printf "\033[036m==> %s <==\033[0m\n", FILENAME;
  }
  # print head lines
  FNR <= n { print }
  # store lines in a circular buffer
  { a[FNR % n]=$0 }
  # print non-overlapping tail lines from circular buffer.
  ENDFILE {
    if ( FNR > 2 * n ) {
      printf "\033[0;36m>>> %s lines skipped <<<\033[0m\n", FNR - 2 * n
    }
    for (i=FNR-n+1;i<=FNR;i++) {
      if ( i > n) {
        print a[i % n]
      }
    }
  }
' "$@"
}
headtail_awk "$@"
```

I'll leave any getopts and/or enhancements of the N=10 line window as an exercise for the reader.

sample output of multiple files (with n=3):

```
$ headtail -n 3 /usr/share/dict/words /usr/share/dict/propernames
==> /usr/share/dict/words <==
A
a
aa
>>> 235880 lines skipped <<<
zythum
Zyzomys
Zyzzogeton
==> /usr/share/dict/propernames <==
Aaron
Adam
Adlai
>>> 1302 lines skipped <<<
Wolfgang
Woody
Yvonne
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
(head -100) < source.txt > target.txt

(head -100) < source.txt takes the first 100 lines from the source.txt file and then

> taget.txt pushes the 100 lines into a new file called target.txt

Initially I thought something like this should work:
head -100 source.txt > target.txt
but it returned an empty file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first *x* and last *y* lines of of output of a command or pipeline, I found it best to use several shell features:

```
(head -n $x; tail -n $y) <<< "$(your_pipeline_here)"
```

`(list)` is a compound command to run `list` in a subshell, `<<<` introduces a here document, `$()` is command substitution, and `""` keeps the line breaks in the pipeline's output.

If you want, you can add `echo;` in between the `head` and `tail` commands to print a blank line (or a non-blank line if you give echo one or more arguments). Note that `-n $x` can be shorted to `-$x` if `$x` expands to a positive integer with no leading `+`. Example:

```
(head -3; echo; tail -4) <<< "$(seq 10)"
```

Output:

```
1
2
3

7
8
9
10
```

Of course, this solution works best if the sum of *x* and *y* is <= the number of lines in the command or pipeline's output. It has the advantage of being able to specify arbitrary line limits for `head` and `tail`, but the disadvantage is that `tail` won't repeat any lines that `head` already printed. Given the use of subshells, it might not perform very well if executed many times. This tradeoff will be worth it for some use cases, but not others.