# 'while head -n 1' curiosities

Tags: bash, while-loop, posix, sh, unix-head

Some *coding experiments*, (made while attempting to find a shorter answer to a coding question), led to a few interesting surprises:

```
seq 2 | while head -n 1 ; do : ; done
```

Output (hit *Control-C* or it'll waste CPU cycles forever):

```
1
^C
```

The same, but using a *redirected input file* instead of *piped input*:

```
seq 2 > two
while head -n 1 ; do : ; done < two
```

Output (hit *Control-C*):

```
1
2
^C
```

Questions:

1. Why does the `while` loop not stop the way `seq 2 | head -n 1` would?
2. Why would *redirected input* produce ***more*** output than *piped input*?

---

The above code was tested with `dash` and `bash` on a recent *Lubuntu*.  Both `seq` and `head` are from the **coreutils** (version *8.25-2ubuntu2*) package.

Method to get around having to hit *(Ctrl-C)*:

```
timeout .1 sh -c "seq 2 > two ; while head -n 1 ; do : ; done < two"
```

> 1
>   2

```
timeout .1 sh -c "seq 2 | while head -n 1 ; do : ; done"
```

> 1

Comment: If nothing else, it's a method of distinguishing redirected input from piped input.  Except the '_Control-C_' is inconvenient.

Comment: Funny, and a still funnier thing is that if you use the `<<` redirect this effect disappears.

Comment: On OS X I cannot reproduce the effect. Even with `< two` I still get only `1`

Comment: What do you think `head -n 1` does when given an empty file on its stdin?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, do you mean 1) `head -n 1 /dev/null`, or plain old 2) `head -n` (wait for user to do something)?

Comment: @Matteo, on linux `head -n 1 /dev/null ; echo $?` returns `0`, is it the same with OS X?

Comment: @agc, I meant the former. `head -n 1 /dev/null` -- what's its exit status? And when the thing in the condition part of a while loop sees that exit status, what action do you expect it to take?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, `0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116532/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-agc).

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13736974/77567) informative.

Comment: Related question: [Pipes, how do data flow in a pipeline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182232/pipes-how-do-data-flow-in-a-pipeline/182242#182242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head -n 1`, when given an empty stream on stdin, is well within its rights and specification to immediately exit with a successful exit status.

Thus:

```
seq 2 | while head -n 1 ; do : ; done
```

...can legally loop forever, as `head -n 1` is not required to exit with a nonzero status and thus terminate the loop. (A nonzero exit status is only required by the standard if "an error occurred", and a file having fewer lines than are requested for output is not defined as an error).

Indeed, this is explicit:

> When a file contains less than *number* lines, it shall be copied to standard output in its entirety. This shall not be an error.

---

Now, **if** your implementation of `head`, after its first invocation, (printing the contents of the first line), leaves the file pointer queued up at the beginning of the second line when it exits, (which it is **absolutely not required to do**), then the second loop instance will then read that second line and emit it. Again, however, this is an implementation detail which depends on whether the folks writing your `head` implementation chose to *either*:

1. Read an aggressively large block, but only emit a subset of it.   (The more efficient implementation.)
2. *Or* loop character-by-character to only consume a single line.

An implementer is well within their rights to decide which of those implementations to follow based on criteria only available at runtime.

---

Now, let's say your `head` *always* tries to read 8kb blocks at a time. How, then, could it ever leave the pointer queued up for the second line? [*** - other than seeking backwards, which [some implementations do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13736974/77567) when given a file, but which is not required by the standard; thanks to *Rob Mayhoff* for the pointer here]

This can happen *if the concurrent invocation of `seq` has only written and flushed a single line as of when the first `read` occurs*.

Obviously, it's a very timing-sensitive situation -- a race condition -- and also depends on unspecified implementation details, (whether `seq` flushes its output between lines -- which, as `seq` is not specified as part of POSIX or any other standard, is completely variant between platforms).

Comment: That's a lot of background, if nobody else tops it, I'll green this later.  Still, this answer is a bit *political* for my tastes, what with words like "rights", "not required", and the limits of standardization.

Comment: As language lawyers go, I'm of the unrepentant variety: If a behavior isn't guaranteed by a specification, it can go away with any platform change, any software upgrade, any runtime environment modification, *without that change in behavior constituting a bug on anyone's part*. Language lawyering (for a wide reading of the term encompassing normative documentation in general) is critical: It helps you understand which behaviors are promises you can trust, and which are present -- or not -- at the whims of whoever last refactored the library you're using.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree...   Re "without...a bug on anyone's part", that recalls two 19th century images depicting mysterious redistributions:  ['Twas Him](http://www.harpweek.com/09Cartoon/BrowseByDateCartoon-Large.asp?Month=August&Date=19), and [Get off the Earth](http://www.moillusions.com/get-off-earth-optical-illusion/).

Comment: On further reflection, some reservations...  This is a good answer, and  _does_ answer the question, but so freely intermixes generalizations with analysis of the specific coding example, that the generalizations tend to obscure the analysis, so that even a day later repeat readings are required.  It would be better if the specific analysis came first, (regarding *coreutils* v8.25-2ubuntu2), and *after* that the survey of the output permutations made possible within the intentionally unspecified lacunae of POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is correct. `head` doesn't return a non-zero for the input (even no input)**

But I did discover some more *curiosities*

---

I figured out a way to do it that halts correctly.

```bash
seq 10 | while head -c 4 | ifne -n false; do : ; done;
```

Sadly there isn't much you can do with the construct because the output of `head` travels over the body of the `while`.

One use I found was to insert a character every x bytes. (including the tail)

```bash
/> printf '12345678910' | { while head -c 2 | ifne -n false; do printf 'a'; done; }
/> 12a34a56a78a91a0a
```

> you should probably use `sed 's/.\{4\}/&a/g'` instead

Here is a slightly more usefull one that will take 2 bytes of input "procees" it then put it somewhere:

```bash
printf '12345678910' | { while true; do head -c 2 < /dev/stdin | ifne -n false >> file.txt || break; done;
```

> you should probably use `split --filter` instead

Another very weird use-case when you try to call `head` inside the while loop with `/dev/stdin`.

```bash
/> printf '12345678910' | { while head -c 2 | ifne -n false; do head -c 3 </dev/stdin | ifne -n false >> every3.txt || break; done > every2.txt; }
/> cat every2.txt
12670
/> cat every3.txt
345891
```

Which, as you can see, cycles every 2 bytes then every 3 bytes.
`12  345  67  891  0`

> you should probably use [`bbe`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bbe) instead

you could possible use it as some kind of poor-mans progress indicator

```bash
/> printf '12345678910' | while head -c 2 | ifne -n false; do echo "2 bytes travelled" > /dev/stderr ; done > /dev/null;
2 bytes travelled
2 bytes travelled
2 bytes travelled
2 bytes travelled
2 bytes travelled
2 bytes travelled # imperfect because actually only 1 byte travelled here
```

> you should probably use [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) instead

---

What can you *actaully* do with this construct...

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I feel like there is something this construct can do that is impossible or very difficult otherwise...
If you have any use-cases, let me know!