# combining cat and tail

Tags: ubuntu, cat, tail

I am trying to combine cat and tail commands:

Like this:

I have file name "text1" and want to combine to file name "text2".
But first I wanted to remove 7 lines from file text1 before I combine to file "text2"

```
     tail --lines=+7 text1 | cat  text2 > out_put
```

This does not work for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [unix - head AND tail of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624669/unix-head-and-tail-of-file)

Comment: +1 for that creative question title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{ tail --lines=+7 text1; cat text2; } > out_put
```

or

```
tail --lines=+7 text1 | cat - text2 > out_put
```

Passing `-` tells cat to read from stdin first, then from text2.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in two steps/commands:

```
tail --lines=+7 text1 > output
cat text2 >> output
```

Or even like this, that will perform the second if the first was successful:

```
tail --lines=+7 text1 > output && cat text2 >> output
```

Note that we use `>>` to append data to the file, so it will be added *after* the previous data existing in the file. With `>` we just delete everything that was there before.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a "here-string" (described in `man bash`):

```
cat - <<< "$(tail --lines=+3 text1)" text2 > out_put
```