# How can I add a newline in between head and tail in Unix?

Tags: unix, zsh

In the following Unix command (I’m in zsh), I’d like to have a blank line appear between the `head` and `tail` of a long text file for readability.

Here’s the command:

```
cat LongTextFile.txt | tee >(head) >(tail) >/dev/null
```

I’m already aware of

```
(head; echo; tail) < LongTextFile.txt
```

but I’m wondering if it’s possible to use the `tee` command.

Comment: If you are not going to output to a file? Why use tee?

Comment: @Raman Sailopal I don’t know that I necessarily need to. I’m just learning UNIX and want to know if the pipe operator can be used to show the head and tail of a long file, with a blank line in between. This seems to be a simple thing, but I can’t get it to work.

Comment: Both `>(head)` and `>(tail)` are executed asynchronously. There's no guarantee (though it is exceedingly likely) that you will even get the output of `head` first.

Comment: Note that `(head; echo; tail)` is not strictly safe either, as `head` can consume more lines of input than it needs to output, possibly consuming input you intended `tail` to get.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Because `tee` doesn't just output to a file; it outputs to one **or more** files, and those files can usefully be Bash process substitutions.

Comment: I understand that but since the poster had already found an alternate solution, I was interested in the reason for focusing on tee.

Comment: I think @Kaz understands what I was trying to get at. But after reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624669/unix-head-and-tail-of-file), I’m not sure that there’s a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process substitutions `>(head) >(tail)` are not sequenced; they run in parallel. `head` and `tail` are running concurrently. `tee` is reading its standard input and distributing it to those two processes. So there is no concept of "between them" where we could insert a newline.

You're just lucky that when the file is long enough, `head` has a chance to finish before `tail` starts outputting anything.

If the file is so small that `head` and `tail` overlap, you may get interleaved output, or reordered output, depending on the exact buffering going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this works in Zsh:

```
print -l "$(head LongTextFile.txt)" '' "$(tail LongTextFile.txt)"
```

Comment: @MarionRichert Thank you for answering, but I was looking for a command that uses piping.

Comment: I’m just learning UNIX and am testing the boundaries of what the pipe operator can do. I’ve made a note of your alternate solution for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
seq 100 | { s=$(cat); head <<<$s; echo; tail <<<$s; }
```